# Creating edges between groups of nodes

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-theory

I have a set of N nodes, divided into S subgroups. The number of nodes in each subgroup is not always equal but the division is as even as possible.

I would like to create edges to form connections between groups, subject to the constraints:

- The maximum degree of each node is k.
- There are at least 2 connections between each group.

Would anybody be able to suggest if a particular algorithm or approach exists for this sort of process? It seems like the sort of thing there would be an established method for, but I've been unable to find anything so far.

*** Update to provide more info (10/11)***

In brief 'pseudo-code":

- Determine all N(N-1)/2 possible combinations of the groups e.g AB, AC, BC etc.

  - Iterate through each of these pairs
  - For each pair:

    - Randomly choose a node in group 1
    - Randomly choose a node in group 2
    - Make a connection between these nodes if:

      - the degrees of both nodes < k
      - the edge does not already exist
- repeat until the required number of connections are present.

The problem I often have is, if the number of groups is greater than the number of nodes in each group, the nodes in the first pairings iterated through are full before the later pairings have a chance to catch up. I've tried randomizing the order I iterate through the possible pairs but it hasn't helped.

I have mitigated this problem a little by deriving some limits in the formation of groups based on the constraints.

Comment: Do you mean, "There are at least 2 connections between each *pair of* groups"?

Comment: What you seem to describe here is a trivial problem.  You draw a "supernode" curve around each group of nodes.  Make two edges between each pair of supernodes.  Finally, take the edge endpoints for each group/supernode and distribute them evenly among the nodes of the group.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the correction.

I had considered that approach, but I (probably naively) thought that redistributing the connections among the "supernodes" would be more difficult to implement than assigning the edges to the nodes directly. The problem with that approach is the distribution of edges becomes very uneven as the early nodes fill up before the later ones.

Thank you for the tip, Prune. I will think on it and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to describe here is a trivial problem. You draw a "supernode" curve around each group of nodes. Make two edges between each pair of supernodes. Finally, take the edge endpoints for each group/supernode and distribute them evenly among the nodes of the group.

**Update per OP comment**

What's this "early nodes" and "later ones"?  If you have more information on the problem, please present it.  You do this in phases:

1. Describe each group as a collection of nodes.
2. Create the N*(N-1) edges connecting all of the groups; label each endpoint with the associated group.
3. For each group, iterate through the associated endpoints, assigning them in round-robin fashion to the group's nodes.

This gives you the required mapping while minimizing the maximum degree in each group.  This will generate an optimal solution, provided one exists.

**Refinement per OP Update 11 Oct**

**ANALYSIS**

You have **N** nodes and **S** subgroups (groups).  This means that you have **N/S** nodes in each group.  Where this is not an integer, you'll have **P=floor(N/S)** nosed in some groups, and **P+1** nodes in the others.

You have a maximum degree **k**; you have a minimum of **N(N-1)** edges, requiring **2(N-1)** edge endpoints in each group.

Lemma: The smaller groups (with P nodes) can support k*P connections.
If k*P < 2(N-1), then you have no solution to the requirements.
Otherwise (i.e. 2(N-1) <= k*P), then you have an equitable solution available through construction.

**Solution**

Order the nodes within each group in any way you like; let's number them 0 through P-1 or P (depending on the group population).  Again within each group, number the group's endpoints 0 through 2(N-1) - 1.

For each group, iterate through the endpoints.  For each endpoint number **i**, assign it to node **i mod P** (or P+1 for the larger groups).  This will allocate all the endpoints evenly among the nodes.

Q.E.D.

Comment: My apologies, I should have given more info on what I had attempted. I was so sure, that I was on the wrong path and that there would be a simple "standard" answer to the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the expanded response. I really appreciate it, although I would just like to clear up a couple of point.

- Using your terminology (S for the number of subgroups) I have S(S-1) as the necessary number of edges, leading to k*P >= 2(S-1). Am I missing something?

- When you say "endpoints" are you referring to the nodes (in the other subgroups) that our node connects to? i.e. the endpoint of node i mod P in the group is node i?

Thanks again. Your help is really helping me sharpen my thinking on this.

Comment: AN "endpoint" is merely one end of an edge.  Each edge has two endpoints, which you need to affix to two different nodes.